# What is the probability to get all qubits equal zero after QFT

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-fourier-transform

*Question from exam:*

Bob built a quantum computer wiht 10 qubits. All qubits are set to zeroes. Bob performed a quantum Fourier transform on the system and then measured the system.

**what is the probability that the result will be 0 (all qubits are zeroes)?**

Comment: I've migrated this here because of [this meta post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/homework-like-question) I hope that's OK.

Answer (score 5):

By looking to the circuit for the QFT presented in the M. Nielsen and I. Chuang [textbook](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB) (Figure 5.1.) we can notice that all controlled rotations can be neglected because for each control rotation gate the control qubits are in $| 0\rangle$ state (for the case described in the question). Here is the Figure from the [book](https://www.cambridge.org/am/academic/subjects/physics/quantum-physics-quantum-information-and-quantum-computation/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-10th-anniversary-edition?format=HB):

[image]

So effectively, in this case, we have only Hadamard gates acting on $n$ qubits. And, of course, Swap gates (will talk about it later). So

$$H^{\otimes n} |000...0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}} \sum_x{|x\rangle}$$

where $H^{\otimes n}$ is the notation of the $n$ Hadamard gates acting on $n$ qubits that are all in the $|0\rangle$ state, $\sum_x{|x\rangle}$ is the sum of all bit strings (from $|000...0\rangle$ to $|111...1\rangle$). Swap gates at the end of the QFT circuit (not presented in the Figure 5.1.) will not change this state: the final state after the swaps will stay the same. So all bit strings have equal amplitudes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}$, and therefore equal probabilities $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\right|^2 = \frac{1}{2^n}$. Thus, the answer is: for 10 qubits we will measure all qubits in the $|0\rangle$ state with $\frac{1}{2^{10}} \approx 0.001$ probability.

Comment: Just posted same answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When input state to QFT is $|00\dots0\rangle$ then no controlled gates in QFT work as each control qubit is set to $|0\rangle$. However, there are also Hadamard gates on each qubit. As a result, QFT behaves as $H^{\otimes n}$ and produces superposition consisting of all basis state with same probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$, where $n$ is number of input qubits.

For your case $n=10$, hence probability that state $|00\dots0\rangle$ is preserved after QFT application is $\frac{1}{1024}.$

Answer (score 3):

The unitary matrix of the Fourier transform is
$$
U_{QFT}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{x,y=0}^{2^n-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{xy}{2^n}}|y\rangle\langle x|.
$$
So, if I apply this to the input state $|0\rangle$, I get the answer
$$
U_{QFT}|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{y=0}^{2^n-1}|y\rangle.
$$
The amplitude for finding the system is state $y=0$ is $1/\sqrt{2^n}$. Hence the probability of this outcome is $1/2^n$ with $n=10$, so the probability is $1/1024$.